# Design an application using to support both synchronous and asynchronous calls

Tags: spring, rest, asynchronous, synchronization, stomp

We are designing an API for an application where the clients (external) can
interact with it synchronously to say: 
a) request a plan 
b) cancel a plan etc

However once the plan is made, the decision as to whether a plan is
 approved or disapproved is done asynchronously. The application itself
 can send other notifications to the clients asynchronously. This part has
 been implemented using spring's stomp over websocket framework. This
 work perfectly fine.

Now, coming to the synchronous part of the API, the plan is to provide
 a RESTful interface for the interaction. If this is done this way, the
 clients will have to build two different client API's, one using http
 for making RESTful calls and another using a stomp client to consume notifications.

Should we rather make it accessible via one interface?

I am not convinced of using Stomp for synchronous calls since I think the REST framework
will address the use case well. However I am concerned about the need for the clients to do both, although it is for different functionality.

Will it be okay to support both? Is this a good design practice. Can someone please advice?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP based clients could a) send requests ('simple polling), in long intervalls to limit bandwidth usage, or b) use HTTP long polling (blocking) to immediately return control to the client code when the server sends for a response